# How to replicate an abstract Fragment in Kotlin to View Controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I am working on implementing an iOS version of an existing Kotlin Android app. The specific feature that I am reproducing is a stepped wizard workflow.

### How I Did it in Android

In Android, the [library that I used](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper) had the following process:

- Add a "stepper" view to a root activity, and provide a `StepAdapter` to this view
- The `StepAdapter` controls the number of steps, and returns each step on request by index.
- Each step is a `Fragment` implementing a `Step` interface that provides hooks for validation and transitioning between steps.

I ended up creating an abstract `Fragment` type that provides default implementations for the `Step` methods:

```
abstract class StepFragment(private val index: Int) : Fragment(), Step {
    ...overriding some methods from Fragment
    ...implementing methods from Step
}
```

Each step's `Fragment` inherits this class, passing a hard coded `index` into `StepFragment`'s constructor. The steps may override some of the methods from `StepFragment`, and some of them call the superclass's implementation as well (I use the `@CallSuper` annotation to facilitate this). The `StepAdapter` instantiates and returns each one of these fragments.

### How I'm Trying to Do it in iOS

Back in the iOS/Swift world, I found a [similar library](https://github.com/amratab/FlexibleSteppedProgressBar), but all it provides is the view for the progress bar. It does not handle instantiating and displaying the content of each step like the Android one does. I need to handle that myself.

You can, however, provide a delegate to the stepper that allows you to hook into the transitions (willSelectIndex, didSelectIndex, canSelectIndex, etc.). I made the root `ViewController` the delegate for the stepper. This `ViewController` has the progress bar view at the top, and a container for each step beneath the progress bar. Each step's `ViewController` is embedded into a corresponding container. To control transitions between steps, I simply show and hide these container views. I have that part figured out.

What I do not have figured out is how to replicate the `StepFragment` class from Android `Fragment`s into Swift `ViewController`s. I have the following problems:

- Swift does not have abstract classes (for some reason).
- I do not instantiate the step `ViewController`s; that is handled internally by the storyboard. This means that I can't provide the step index in the constructor like I can in Android. An abstract property would be the typical way to get around this, but (see above) Swift doesn't have abstract classes.

I could get around these problems in a few ways:

- Instead of an abstract class, I can use a protocol. I can specify the requirement that all classes that conform to the protocol must be `ViewController`s, but I cannot override methods from `ViewController` in the protocol (as far as I've been able to see). I can add an extension to the protocol to provide functions with default implementations, which implementors can then override, and they can even call into the original functions (using `(self as Protocol).func()`). However, this feels very clunky.
- Instead of an abstract class, I can use a regular class. I can achieve everything that I want to here, except that I can't enforce that the subclass implements abstract members at compile time. I would need to use something like `fatalError()` in the base class, which only throws at runtime. This also feels clunky.
- I keep hearing about the "delegate" pattern, and I think it's a nice elegant way to solve a lot of problems in a "Swifty" way, but I have no idea how I would use that here. I think I would prefer being able to do it this way over the above two.

### TL;DR

To sum up my problem, I am looking for a way for multiple "step" child `ViewController`s to hook into a wizard workflow controlled by a parent `ViewController`. They should be able to perform some (potentially async) logic on step selection, before transitions, and even block transitions. I must be able to optionally ignore some of these hooks, which should then use a default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you actually *can* provide default implementations for protocol functions, so this is the solution I came to:

```swift
protocol StepViewController: UIViewController {
    var stepIndex: Int { get }

    func onBackClicked(_ goToPreviousStep: () -> Void)

    ...
}

extension StepViewController {
    // this is a default implementation, so implementors don't have to provide it
    func onBackClicked(_ goToPreviousStep: () -> Void) {
        goToPreviousStep()
    }

    ...
}

class StepOneViewController: UIViewController, StepViewController {
    let stepIndex: Int = 0

    func onBackClicked(_ goToPreviousStep: () -> Void) {
        // if I want to call the default implementation I can do this:
        (self as StepViewController).onBackClicked(goToPreviousStep)
    }
}
```